# Prove by induction a result of the form. Use best possible value for T

Tags: induction

can anyone show me how to solve this?
possile solution

Prove by induction a result of the form “for all n ≥ T, 2n < n!”. Use the best possible value of T.

Answer (score 1):

Well you first need to conjecture some value of $T$. You see that the inequality is wrong for $T=1,2,3$ but true for $T=4$. So here is our conjecture :
$$
n \geq 4 \implies 2n < n!
$$
Then you prove it by induction. The base case will indeed be at $n=4$ and is trivial.

Regarding the induction step you can say :
$$
(n+1)! = n!\cdot (n+1) \overset{(*)}{>} 2n(n+1)
$$
$(*)$ inductive hypothesis.

I let you finish.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily said. We take $T=4$.

Then $$n!=n×(n-1)×... ×2×1$$.
Thus $n!=2n×((n-1)!÷2)$.

(n-1)!÷2 is always greater than 1 for all n > 3. We do not need induction the problem is obvious.